# Should a married woman nullify chametz too?

Tags: halacha, women, chametz-leaven

Rav Shimon Eider in the Halachos of Pesach (IX:C:5) says: "Some [Poskim](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1428/) hold that a married woman should nullify personal chometz." However, in footnote 70 Rabbi Eider writes this isn't found in printed books, but he has heard this from Poskim.

Are there Poskim nowadays who specifically require or exempt married women from the chametz-nullification procedure?

Comment: Why would she be possibly be exempt?

Comment: See here for an extensive review of the subject. https://www.sefaria.org/Gray_Matter_III%2C_Beit_Din%2C_Marital_Finances_in_Light_of_Contemporary_Arrangements?ven=Gray_Matter,_by_Chaim_Jachter._Teaneck,_N.J,_2000-2012&lang=bi

Comment: @Chatzkel the question was about her personal chametz. Everyone agrees a married woman can have personal chametz; that article is just about how common such a situation is likely to be nowadays

Comment: The first paragraph relates a story how he called his wife to remind her to be mevatel her chametz and the debate that ensued with the other rabbonim. He then explains why today marital financial relationship might be different than in earlier times.

Comment: @Chatzkel Yes. And how common it is for married women to own chametz is, again, not the question asked. What the default marital financial relationship may be nowadays is only relevant to how common it is for married women to own chametz.

Comment: Incidentally, is anyone obligated to nullify chametz? You can just destroy all your chametz instead.

Comment: @double AA The question actually was if there are poskim that specifically require or exempt women from being mevatel. The link I posted provides an answer by mentioning the story and that there were those who agreed and those who argued.

Comment: @Chatzkel No no no, the people in that story are just debating if most married women in their communities own any chametz. Your misrepresentation is very dangerous lest some married woman who unambiguously owns chametz sees this and mistakenly thinks anyone exempts her from ridding herself of ownership of her chametz.